# Understanding PDF_info_matchbox

Tags: php, pdflib

Can anyone please explain the usage of PDF_info_matchbox. I have read the PHP Manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-info-matchbox.php but it is not very clear.

`float PDF_info_matchbox ( resource $pdfdoc , string $boxname , int $num , string $keyword )`

Neither can I understand the meaning of matchbox

Kindly explain the usage of individual parameters if possible.

Examples will be really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Matchboxes provide access to coordinates calculated by PDFlib as a result of placing 
some content on the page.

You will find an overview about the matchbox concept in PDFlib in Chapter "8.4 Matchboxes" of the PDFlib Tutorial. The tutorial can be found in the doc directory of your PDFlib installation or at http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/manuals/PDFlib-9.0.1-tutorial.pdf.

http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/text-output/wrap-text-around-images/ is an example showing the usage of matchboxes to wrap some text around images.